# Chroot SFTP vs wordpress ... omfg? Centos

Tags: ssh, php, apache-2.4

I want to be as much secure as i can. It means, i use only secure ssh on other than default port and auth with cert keys. It works with Winscp, i need cert, cert passphrase to login.

Now i wanted to set up a secure sftp for wordpress. As i mentioned fo use chroot for user his ChrootDirectory must be root:root, is it right? So it can not be /var/www/html/webpage/public_html catalog. I can not use sftpuser (or group) and give him home directory at /var/www/html/webpage/public_html.

How to fix it? How can i install wordpress plugins, themes etc from wp. with sshonly user and chroot dir?
Does ChrootDirectory have an option to exclude subcatalogs? If i use /home/user as a chrooted dir, can i give access to /home/user/A but deny /home/user/B ?

And i can not achieve my goal with sshd. There is on wp pages something like this:

```
define( 'FTP_BASE', '/path/to/wordpress/' );
define( 'FTP_CONTENT_DIR', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/' );
define( 'FTP_PLUGIN_DIR ', '/path/to/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/' );
define( 'FTP_PUBKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' );
define( 'FTP_PRIKEY', '/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa' );
define( 'FTP_USER', 'username' );
define( 'FTP_PASS', 'password' );
define( 'FTP_HOST', 'ftp.example.org' );
define( 'FTP_SSL', false );
```

As i understand it allows wordpress to use connection via ftp/sftp using PHP without using ssh?

SO, why, when i give option DIRECT and change user name to wrong one - WP installs themes without any problem?

It it not working properly?

Comment: Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

## Ssh server:

moving ssh to other port does not make it secure, you will only avoid automatic scanners and scripts (less spam in log files), nothing else. To make ssh more secure, disable root login, disable password login and allow ssh from only trusted IP addresses. If you dont't have static IP address you can block regions you dont need ( asia, africa, etc...)

## FTP server:

ChrootDirectory is not a directory that belongs to user root but its a directory to which user will be logged in. You definitely should create ftp account and chroot it to directory /var/www/html/webpage/public_html. Then change the default group of the ftp user to www-data (or other group you have in your public_html folder) for the user to access files there.

## Wordpress:

You do not need ftp to install updates/plugins. You can change it to direct and make sure wordpress (apache/nginx/php) have write accces to folder plugins or give it 777 permission:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 wp-content/plugins
```